# Using BottomBar prevents fragments from opening?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-support-library

I am using the Support Library to add a bottom bar similar to the material design one. The bottom bar works great but it seems that if I have the bar displayed, if I try to open any fragment from my custom adapter, the fragment does not open...or maybe it opens behind my main layout? I have no idea how to figure this out. Below is my code.

I've read more posts on SO and around the web and I think this is related to the fragment being properly loaded but below or next to the bottom bar...and that is why it isn't visible? Why does this happen? Is it because the bottom bar has a LinearLayout? I defined it as a menu so I'm not sure if I can control it being a LinearLayout....

Setting up the bottom bar, this method is called from the onCreate of my activity:

```
public void setupBottomToolbar(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mBottomBar = BottomBar.attach(MainActivity.this, savedInstanceState);
        mBottomBar.setItems(R.menu.bottombar_menu);

        mBottomBar.setOnMenuTabClickListener(new OnMenuTabClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMenuTabSelected(@IdRes int menuItemId) {
                if (menuItemId == R.id.toolbar_jobs) {

                } else if (menuItemId == R.id.toolbar_messages) {

                } else if (menuItemId == R.id.toolbar_recentJobs) {

                } else if (menuItemId == R.id.toolbar_employerPools) {

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onMenuTabReSelected(@IdRes int menuItemId) {
                if (menuItemId == R.id.toolbar_jobs) {
                    // The user reselected item number one, scroll your content to top.
                } else if (menuItemId == R.id.toolbar_messages) {

                } else if (menuItemId == R.id.toolbar_employerPools) {

                } else if (menuItemId == R.id.toolbar_recentJobs) {

                }
            }
        });

        // Setting colors for different tabs when there's more than three of them.
        // You can set colors for tabs in three different ways as shown below.
        mBottomBar.getBar().setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.laborswipe_darkgray));
        mBottomBar.setActiveTabColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.laborswipe_lightgray));

        // Make a Badge for the second tab, with red background color and a value of "13".
        BottomBarBadge unreadMessages = mBottomBar.makeBadgeForTabAt(1, getResources().getColor(R.color.laborswipe_orange), 5);

        // Control the badge's visibility
        unreadMessages.show();
        //unreadMessages.hide();

        // Change the displayed count for this badge.
        //unreadMessages.setCount(4);

        // Change the show / hide animation duration.
        unreadMessages.setAnimationDuration(200);

        // If you want the badge be shown always after unselecting the tab that contains it.
        unreadMessages.setAutoShowAfterUnSelection(true);

        // If you don't want this badge to be hidden after selecting the tab contains it.
        unreadMessages.setAutoShowAfterUnSelection(false);
    }
```

In my adapter, I am trying to open the fragment when you click a button, like this:

```
holder.desc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Open Description", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                JobDescFragment firstFragment = new JobDescFragment();
                ((MainActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
            }
        });
```

If I comment out the call to setupBottomToolbar() in my onCreate of the activity, the fragment opens up fine...but that means I don't have the bottom bar...

What am I missing? There has to be a way to use the bottom bar and also open a fragment?

Thanks!

### EDIT:

Here is the top part of my activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<String> swipecardsList;
    private ArrayList<Job> jobList = new ArrayList<Job>();
    private JobAdapter arrayAdapter; //arrayadapter
    private BottomBar mBottomBar;
    SharedPreferences settings;

    @InjectView(R.id.frame) SwipeFlingAdapterView flingContainer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Remove title bar
        //this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        //color the notification bar with our company colors
        Window window = this.getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.laborswipe_notificationbar));

        //remove title from action bar and add the logo to the top left of the action bar
        setupTopToolbar();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);

        //set up the bottom toolbar using the roughike library to mimic android material design
        setupBottomToolbar(savedInstanceState);
```

My adapter:

```
public class JobAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Job> {
    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<Job> jobs;
    private final int layoutResourceId;
    private final SwipeFlingAdapterView flingContainer;
    private boolean isExpanded = false;

    public JobAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Job> jobs, SwipeFlingAdapterView flingContainer) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, jobs);
        this.context = context;
        this.jobs = jobs;
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.flingContainer = flingContainer;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        String pay, hrs;
        final Bundle fragmentParams = new Bundle();

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_jobTitle);
            holder.desc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_JobDesc);

            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        }

        Job j = jobs.get(position);

        holder.title.setText(j.getJobTitle());
        holder.desc.setText(j.getDescription());

        //when user clicks apply, swipe the card right
        holder.apply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Open up a fragment to display the entire job description
                Toast.makeText(context, "Applied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                flingContainer.getTopCardListener().selectRight();
            }
        });

        //when user clicks dismiss, swipe the card left
        holder.dismiss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Open up a fragment to display the entire job description
                Toast.makeText(context, "Dismissed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                flingContainer.getTopCardListener().selectLeft();
            }
        });

        //on click event listener for the job description field - open larger window to read description
        holder.desc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Toast.makeText(context, "Open Description", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                JobDescFragment firstFragment = new JobDescFragment();
                Fragment frag = new Fragment();
                frag = firstFragment.newJobDescFrag(j.getDescription());

                ((MainActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag)
                    .addToBackStack("JobDesc").commit();
            }
        });


        return view;
    }

    public class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView title;
        TextView payrate;
        TextView dateRange;
        TextView workinghrs;
        TextView location;
        TextView companyname;
        TextView desc;
        TextView experience;
        TextView equipment;
        Button apply, dismiss, expand;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <com.lorentzos.flingswipe.SwipeFlingAdapterView
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:background="@color/laborswipe_lightgray"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:layout_gravity="top"   />

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</merge>
```

Fragment Layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".JobDescFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/outerDescriptionLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/swipecard_shadow"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/DescriptionLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="#00FF00"
            android:clickable="true">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:text="Detailed Description:"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:id="@+id/tv_title" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:text="THIS IS THE FULL DESCRIPTION"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:id="@+id/tv_fullDescription" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
08-07 11:20:47.799 13896-13896/com.lorentzos.swipecards.example I/System.out: DEBUG: job desc fragment loaded!
08-07 11:20:47.855 13896-13941/com.lorentzos.swipecards.example W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-07 11:20:47.855 13896-13941/com.lorentzos.swipecards.example W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xaaa7f880, error=EGL_SUCCESS
08-07 11:20:48.002 13896-13941/com.lorentzos.swipecards.example V/RenderScript: 0xa1408000 Launching thread(s), CPUs 2
08-07 11:20:49.798 13896-13941/com.lorentzos.swipecards.example E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xae433ca0
```

When I use the bottom bar (not working- no fragment opened but toast displayed):

[image]

When I don't use the bottom bar (workin-fragment opened, background is green):

[image]

Comment: I will appreciate if you share all your code because I can't see what type of Activity you are using and where you call setupBottomToolbar() in code :)

Comment: I have included the top part of my activity as the rest is mostly click listeners and an AsyncTask. Let me know if that helps! I've also added my entire adapter code

Comment: I am not an android pro but I'll try to figure it out and tell you If I succeeded.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks a lot for the help @MaskedMan

Comment: Can you post your activity_main.xml

Comment: @A.R. please see the original post.

Comment: Try changing the Fragment attribute `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to `wrap_content` like: `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and see if this helps. Also, it might be helpful to post the logs (are there errors when you try to show the Fragment?)

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla I tried changing the layout and it did not help, I updated my original post with the logcat messages. Not sure if those are helpful.

Comment: The log would be more helpful if it comes from the `JobDescFragment` itself - so maybe add some debug statements in the `onCreateView` Lifecycle methods of `JobDescFragment` and see if the logs get displayed. This will indicate if the Fragment does get loaded.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla looks like the fragment gets loaded, I added the System.out.println to the onCreate() and I see the message in the log. You can see the log in the updated original post. I think maybe the fragment is there but behind the rest of the layout? I have no idea what is going on

Comment: why are you using the `<merge>` in the activity layout?

Comment: @MaskedMan I have a different layout that I want to include but I removed it to see if that is causing the issue. Once I can get this resolved, I will add that <include> back :) so there is something to merge.

Comment: @MaskedMan any luck? I still can't get to the bottom of this one :(

Comment: Where's the initialization of `firstFragment` in `JobAdapter class`?

Comment: @MaskedMan I've added the onClickListener in my adapter, I initialize the firstFragment within the listener, please see my updated JobAdapter code in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

try to link a pic of problem and without problem(no bottombar) and since you are using `merge` the layout hierarchy will be laid off according to your `activity's` `viewgroup`(linear,relative) `constraints`(we don't know what they are like).

as you said when there is **no bottombar** ,you **fragment displays perfectly** though when the bottombar it there ,problem stats ,as per your log in fragment indicating that your fragment is loading perfectly even though when bottombar is visible mean fragment is there but is not visible ,seems like your fragment didn't get the appropriate space to get displayed.

other solution can be adding bottom bar to your fragment instead of activity to avoid any overlapping ,like

```
mBottomBar.attach(findViewById(R.id.fragmentContainer), savedInstanceState);
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't think I can add the bottom bar to my fragment as that fragment is opened from an adapter and I would the bottom bar to be created from the main activity rather than the adapter. Should I be using a different viewgroup other than linear? I have added my layout file to the original post if that helps.

Comment: I have also added screenshots of how the fragment is opening without the bottom bar.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think the solution for this should be simple, from what I can see in your code, you are attaching the BottomBar to your activity, I think this is the problem. If you were to read the readme.md in the roughike/BottomBar github page you'd find this

> **Why is it overlapping my Navigation Drawer?**
>
> All you need to do is instead of attaching the BottomBar to your Activity, attach it to the view that has your content. For example, if your fragments are in a ViewGroup that has the id fragmentContainer, you would do something like this:
> `mBottomBar.attach(findViewById(R.id.fragmentContainer), savedInstanceState);`

So, since navigation drawer works with transition a fragment in and out of view with animation, the same thing is happening when you are adding a new fragment to your activity.

**The Solution**

From what I can see in your code, your fragment container id is this: `fragment_container` in your activity layout. So according to the documentation you'd just need to do attach your bottomBar to the `fragment_container` instead of MainActivity.this

```
mBottomBar.attach(findViewById(R.id.fragment_container), savedInstanceState);
```

**If the above doesn't work try this**

What you'd need to do is add an extra FrameLayout to hold your bottombar, which has a transparent background, but is on top of your fragment.

So change your main_activity layout to

```
<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <com.lorentzos.flingswipe.SwipeFlingAdapterView
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:background="@color/laborswipe_lightgray"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:layout_gravity="top"   />

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/holder_bottombar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

</merge>
```

Now in the code instead of attaching the bottom bar to mainactivity, just attach it to the holder like so

```
mBottomBar.attach(findViewById(R.id.holder_bottombar), savedInstanceState);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply @bhargav, sorry for my late response. I tried both approaches you mentioned and neither seems to work. I agree with you that it looks like the bottom bar is attached to the wrong layout but It doesn't look like a second FrameLayout is helping. Any other ideas? Again, thanks for the help!